# Equation of motion of a free particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, geodesics

We know that the equation of motion of particle can be derived from the respective action. But in the book I am reading, the author is saying:

> ... timelike worldline of a massive particle is parametrised by proper time, $x^a=x^a(\tau)$. The velocity (tangent) vector is $u^a \equiv \dot{x}^a(\tau)$. This is normalised as $u^au_a =-c^2$.

How can one derive e.o.m?

Comment: well I think we would need more info to continue, but from the last equation it appears that we are talking about a *free* particle, that is, one that is not interacting with anything in any way. So depending on the context, the author might only be using that fact.

Comment: Which author? Oh nevermind: It seems to be eqs. (1.46-47) p. 33 in [M. Blau](http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/Lecturenotes.html), _Lecture notes on GR._

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? You're aware that the EQM can be derived from the action, so are you looking for a more intuitive approach? If so, isn't it just that the definition of a free particle is that its four velocity is constant?

Comment: @JohnRennie "isn't it just that the definition of a free particle is that its four velocity is constant?" Can you give me a source that states this?

Comment: [Will Wikipedia do?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration) I quote: *A corollary is that all inertial observers always have a proper acceleration of zero.*.